# Searching for sentences in get_sentences

Tags: r

I am analysing some amazon reviews. At the current step of my analysis, I'd like to take the sentences written in reviews that have less than two stars. I have done that, applied get sentences, and wrote this function in order to search for words inside the sentences and print out only those containing all of the words:

```
    ricerca <- function(sentences,keyword){
    found <- lapply(sentences, function(x) grep(keyword, x, value = TRUE))
    found <-found[lengths(found) > 0]
    return(found)
```

The sentences are made in the following way:

```
> class(frasi_negative)
[1] "get_sentences"           "get_sentences_character" "list"                   
> frasi_negative[1:2]
[[1]]
 [1] "Auricolari comodissimi."                                                                                  
 [2] "Restano incollati alle orecchie e non cadono in nessuna situazione."                                      
 [3] "Suono limpido, pulito."                                                                                   
 [4] "Bassi consistenti."                                                                                       
 [5] "La durata della batteria è più che soddisfacente (io li ho usati anche per 4 ore di fila senza problemi)."
 [6] "Decisamente soddisfatto."                                                                                 
 [7] "Li ricomprerei."                                                                                          
 [8] "Amazon perfetta come al solito."                                                                          
 [9] "AGGIORNAMENTO RECENSIONE!!!!!"                                                                            
[10] "- Dopo un mese di utilizzo non è più possibile ricaricare le cuffie."                                     
[11] "Non danno più segni di vita."                                                                             
[12] "Delusissimo."                                                                                             
[13] "Non mi sarei mai aspettato una fine così."                                                                
[14] "Peccato perché il prodotto era praticamente perfetto."                                                    

[[2]]
[1] "Al mio cellulare (Xiaomi Redmi Note 5) si mostrano singolarmente, separate, quando cerco di connetterle."                                                   
[2] "O si connette alla destra, o alla sinistra, e in ogni caso il suono poi esce dalle casse del cellulare (nonostante aver dato alle cuffie tutti i permessi)."
[3] "Non capisco perché, data che la prima connessione era andata come si deve; spente e riaccese, hanno iniziato a comportarsi così."                           
[4] "Ho provato a riavviare sia loro che cellulare, a rimetterle nella scatoletta e ritoglierle, ma il problema persiste."                                       
[5] "Non penso c'entri il mio cellulare (mai avuto problemi con prodotti simili), in ogni caso effettuo reso con rimborso."
```

When I try searching for a word, it seems to work (even if the output is really horrible):

```
> found<-ricerca(frasi_negative, "qualità")
> found[1:3]
[[1]]
[1] "Pessima qualità."                                                                                                                                                                               
[2] "La qualità delle chiamate telefoniche è assolutamente pessima (il proprio interlocutore non riceve in modo chiaro la nostra voce, dunque, risultano inutilizzabili come aurocolari telefonici)."

[[2]]
[1] "imbarazzanti non so la gente qui come fanno a dargli 5 stelle, l'unica cosa che mi viene in mente e che non hanno mai provato un paio di cuffie decenti, qualità dell audio pessima si sente basso e male , l'unica cosa buona e che la batteria si comporta bene - a distanza di 20 cm ogni tanto si scollegano provato con piu dispositivi sicuramente richiedo il rimborso davvero pessime"

[[3]]
[1] "La qualità costruttiva è ottima, l'accoppiamento è avvenuto in maniera facile ed immediata, e la durata è ottima."
```

But when I try searching for a few words (as example `c("quality","bad")`), it only searches for the first word, and gets me lot of warnings.

I have no idea about how to adapt this function, so thanks to all of you in advance.

Library: sentimentr

UPDATE:
Thanks for the answers, but it seems that in both the function you guys published it outputs all sentences containing at least one of the two words. I just want to see those which contain both. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The below function should iterate through an inputted vector of keywords:

```
ricerca <- function(sentences,keywords){
  for(i in 1:length(keywords){
    found <- lapply(sentences, function(x) grep(keywords[i], x, value = TRUE))
    found <-found[lengths(found) > 0]
    return(found)
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try combining the `keyword` using `paste` as one string.

```
ricerca <- function(sentences,keyword){

  found <- lapply(sentences, function(x) 
                   grep(paste0(keyword, collapse = "|"), x, value = TRUE))
  found <-found[lengths(found) > 0]
  return(found)
}
```